# Accidentally deleted /Library/Developer files

Tags: xcode, library

I accidentally deleted my /Library/Developer files while trying to delete the Derived Data. Now, My Xcode 9 has stopped working and is crashing everytime I open it. I have a extremely important project pending.
I am using macOS Sierra.

Comment: Are you using Time Machine to back up your Mac?

Comment: No. I am afraid I am not. What are my options?

Comment: Reinstalling the Developer tools is your only option, I guess.

Comment: you mean the command-line tools? If not, where do I find them.

Comment: No further help from me, unfortunately. Reinstall all the Developer software.

Comment: 1 backup all your data, then 2 re-install Xcode, 3 hope it works

Comment: @SolarMike None of them worked. Tried all of it. Even downloading Xcode and Commandline tools. I will try to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Open Terminal from Application -> Utility -> Terminal
Type in the following.

```
xcode-select --install
```

This should install Mac Osx commandline tools and also create the /Library/Developer Files